# Flask/Ajax request seems to have no data - Cannot parse it

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

I am trying to get the name value of the form on the flask back-end and add it to the database.
When I try and get the keys, or values out of the request, but it seems that nothing is going through. Trying a couple different things, I get just gotten a `Response object @ ...`, a `b'...'` response, an immutable list that did not have anything. I am pretty stumped.

I have tried quite a few suggestions here on SO. Unfortunately, quite a few seem to be using jQuery. The rest did not seem to yield anything of substance that I would crack the code on.

My Flask Code:

```
@app.route('/add-name', methods=['POST'])
def add_stage():
    print(request)
    # name = New_Item(name=request.form.get('name'))
    # db.session.add(stage)
    # db.session.commit()
    data = {'response': 'OK'}
    return jsonify(data);
```

My JS code:

```
<form id="name_form" action="" method="POST">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name"/>
</form>'


var my_form = document.getElementById("name_form");


my_form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '/add-name', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    // Also tried request.send(data) where data was the value.
    // Also tried request.send({'data': data } where data was the value.
    request.send(my_form);
  });
```

Can anyone get me some pointers on this? I am pretty new to Ajax and can see its benefits.

Added JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/396rpLzm/

Comment: Is your JS in <script> tags?

Comment: it is indeed. Just reduced my code  in the above snippets to be simple as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your form into a FormData object:

```
var my_form = document.getElementById("name_form");
var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
var FD = new FormData(my_form);
XHR.open("POST", '/add-name');
XHR.send(FD);
```

Comment: So with that A request object is printed. However, `stage_name = request.form.get('data') ## or this ## stage_name = request.form.get('new_stage_name')` both return None

Comment: Neither `data` nor `new_stage_name` are inputs in your form. Try `request.form.get('name')`, you might also need to give you input a `name` attribute i.e. `<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `request.form.get('name')` Let me try with the name attribute. that might be the issue.

Comment: +1 it worked. I was missing the name attribute then needed to pass a FormData object. Thanks a lot! Follow-up question: is there a lot of overhead in a FormData versus say just one variable. Would something like `XHR.send({'name': name})` work? I guess my follow-up is what are other ways of passing variables! Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, so the above caused some other issues down the road. I wanted to point out that @Vorsprung durch Technik posted an answer where he said that the send line:
should be `request.send("name=" + name);` I am not entirely sure why this worked but it did.

With the answer about using FormData, when I printed out the request.form, I got:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('-----------------------------
231208931201322113290\r\nContent-Disposition: 
form-data; name', 
'"name"\r\n\r\nTest\r\n-----------------------------
231208931201322113290--\r\n')])
```

which does not want to be assessed. (Changed the numbers in case they are sensitive. Does that have something to do with the security token? I saw some posts about jinja csrf tokens and JS security tokens causing some issues...maybe that is part of it.).